# BlackBerry App World Submission Process with multiple 'binaries' and overwriting side-loaded app

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

I currently develop an app that I have have my own OTA download site, where I check the useragent to determine the build to let the user download. I have this simply because I created the app before the App World was released.

I have since then updated the app, and now have TWO binaries: 1 for devices running 4.5-4.9, and one for 5.0 and above.

The app has never been in the App World before.

I am wondering two things:

Will an OTA (side-loaded?) app be overwritten with an App World update, provided they have the same source-layout (packages)

Can I submit two apps under 1 title, and have different binaries (1 for < 5.0 devices, one for > 5.0).

I need this simply because I use some features not in OS < 5.0, so I have to 'dumb' down the build a bit.

I tried posting on the BlackBerry Dev. forums, but they seem dead, and I wasn't able to find either of these issues via. Google.

Has anyone dealt with this issue? A link to documentation would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the first issue (whether it will overwrite the existing one) as I haven't actually tried it before. However, you can submit multiple builds under the same title.

What forum are you posting to? I regularly visit the [BB Java Development](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/bd-p/java_dev) forums and they are quite active.